# How do I prevent a list comprehension from including empty values?

Tags: python, list

So I have the following code:

```
columns1 = [row[d] for d in cols if d != '']
```

However it isn't preventing empty values from being put into columns1.

What's a good way to either purge empty values, or preferably prevent them from insertion altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this?

```
columns1 = [row[d] for d in cols if row[d] != '']
                                    ^^^^ ^
```